Why does Next.js image optimization change my image to a square only in production?
I have an image rendered using the Next.js Image component, hosted on imgbb. Everything works fine on my local environment, but after deploying to Vercel, the image’s dimensions become strange, and it appears as a square. I suspect that sharp might be transforming it into a square during optimization.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Is there any way to fix this problem? It's been troubling me for a while.
<Image
  className="mb-5 w-full rounded-lg object-cover"
  src={coverImage}
  alt={title}
  width={1000}
  height={500}
/>

local

request:
http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ibb.co%2F3c3VzBX%2Fvagrant-cover.jpg&w=750&q=75
production in vercel

request :
https://example.vercel.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ibb.co%2F3c3VzBX%2Fvagrant-cover.jpg&w=750&q=75

The issue with your image becoming square in production is likely due to Next.js optimization. Here's how you can try fix it:

Aspect Ratio: Remove or adjust width and height props to maintain the image's natural aspect ratio.

Disable Optimization: Add the unoptimized attribute to prevent resizing issues:
<Image
  className="mb-5 w-full rounded-lg object-cover"
  src={coverImage}
  alt={title}
  width={1000}
  height={500}
  unoptimized
/>



